# Is VolatileImage thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a multithread model. When one thread throws some event we need to paint something on VolatileImage. Here is some code:

```
private VolatileImage image;

private void buff() {
    image = createVolatileImage(200, 200, Transparency.OPAQUE);
}

public void paintCircle(int x, int y, int h, int w) {
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.fillOval(x, y, h, w);

}
```

Can this method(paintCircle) get me some troubles without synchronized keyword?

Comment: Since it's not documented as being thread-safe, you should assume that it's not.

Comment: Actually, it resides in java.awt package which is known to be thread safe. However, the way the field is updated isn't thread safe.

Comment: How should anyone tell whether this single method can get into trouble when no one knows what the other threads are doing?

Comment: @Holger AWT allows this. It's a design decision (which turned out to be very wrong) which was made by the AWT authors.

Comment: @Konstantin Solomatov: AWT is thread safe if used correctly. But you can’t tell from a single method whether this program uses AWT correctly. If two threads are painting to the same image concurrently, the result will still be unpredictable. As you said in your answer, you simply don’t know which thread invokes `buff()` and hence, whether the update will propagate to the thread invoking `paintCircle(…)`. The same applies to the relationship between the thread invoking `paintCircle(…)` and the possibly existing thread trying to paint that image to the screen. As I said *we simply don’t know*.

Comment: @Holger Yes, you are right. What I wanted to say, is that you can call VolatileImage methods from different threads.

Answer (score 2):

Java memory model uses happens-before relation to describe when changes from on thread are visible in the other. If you call buff, in one thread and then paint in AWT event dispatch thread, the changes from buff might not propagate to EDT, so you should enforce this relation. One way to do this is to use synchronized keyword or make the image field volatile.